# Delete files based on path stored in vector

Tags: r, delete-file

I already checked several question on SO. This questions is different because asks to delete several files based on paths stored in a vector.

I have a vector:

```
rds_files <- paste0("C://mypath//file", 1:10, ".rds")
```

Each element of the vector represent the path of a file I need to delete.

Can you suggest me one of the possible approaches to automatically delete all those files?

Comment: I already checked some questions on SO. This is different because it asks to delete based on path stored in a vector

Comment: In the dupe link suppose you assign it  `files <- list.files("C:/Temp", full.names = TRUE))` it will again do the same thing `do.call(file.remove, list(files))`

Comment: Solution in linked question works for me: `for (i in 1:10) {saveRDS(1, paste0("file", i, ".RDS"))}; rds_files <- paste0("file", 1:10, ".rds"); do.call(file.remove, list(rds_files))`

Comment: Clear, thank you for help!